# An import mistake in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, I want to run a python3 program which was cloned from github, but i meet some question about import.
The structure of it is that:

```
$ tree .
.
├── readme.md
├── requirements.txt
├── service
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── decorator.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── spider.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_grade_api.py
└── wsgi.py
```

The __ init __.py in `tests` is that:

```
from service import app
from .test_grade_api import test_grade_api

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_grade_api(app)
```

The __ init __.py in `service` is that:

```
import base64
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp_session import setup, get_session, session_middleware
from aiohttp_session.cookie_storage import EncryptedCookieStorage
from cryptography import fernet

def create_app():
    app = web.Application()
    fernet_key = fernet.Fernet.generate_key()
    secret_key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(fernet_key)
    # ====== app set ======
    setup(app, EncryptedCookieStorage(secret_key))
    # =====================

    # ====== url map ======
    # =====================

    # ====== sub app ======
    from .api import api
    app.add_subapp('/api/', api)
    # =====================
    return app

app = create_app()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

But When I `python3 __init__.py` in `test`, It tells me that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from service import app
ImportError: No module named 'service'
```

What is the mistake?

Comment: Did you forget the top level `__init__.py`?

Comment: try adding your top level directory (the one which contains `service`  and `test`) in the [Python path](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) (see also [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no visibility of the `service` from within `test`.

3 solutions:

1 - Add `service` to your PYTHONPATH variable

2 - Execute code from the root directory (i.e. `cd test/;cd ../`)

3 - Symbolic link to `service` from `test`, i.e. `ln -s service ../service/`